# Firebase: Cannot find module "ts-morph"

Tags: firebase, node-modules, ts-morph

I have an express application that is deployed in firebase, and uses firebase-functions v3.21.0, to which I have made some modifications that have required the use of "ts-morph" package, but whenever I try to deploy this app to firebase servers, it generates the error mentioned in the title, and exits, even though this package is installed and present in node modules.

Deleted node modules and tried npm i again (the package ts-morph is present in package json)